# How to get why an app crashed?

Tags: crashes, troubleshooting

I regularly obtain the infamously unhelpful "unfortunately crappyApp has stopped working". How to figure out what actually went wrong? I guess there's a stack trace somewhere, though ideally I'd like to modify the unhelpful message itself if that is possible on a rooted device.

Comment: For a starter, we have the [troubleshooting tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/troubleshooting/info) ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can simply see the crash stack trace after any crash happens.
Use ADB command below,

```
adb logcat -b crash #default
adb -d logcat -b crash #show from device when multiple device
adb -s logcat -b crash #show from simulator when multiple device
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to obtain useful information. But as [Dan pointed out](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/86384/how-to-get-why-an-app-crashed#comment-109674), on-device solutions will require root (starting with JellyBean) – and off-device solutions ADB:

- `adb logcat` was already described in [Dan's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/86390/16575). For more details, you can see our [logging](/questions/tagged/logging) [tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/logging/info).
- `adb bugreport > report.txt` gives very detailed information, including details from the `dumpsys`, `dumpstate`, and `logcat` tools. Several tools for easier analysis of its output can be found e.g. in the answers to [Better method of viewing “adb bugreport” output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7799434/2533433) on our sister-site.
- there are tools to be installed on your computer which utilize the above (or at least parts of it), like [QtADB](http://qtadb.wordpress.com/) (for Linux, Mac, and Windows)
- there are Android apps like [Bug Reporter](http://www.appbrain.com/app/bug-reporter/com.bh.android.bugreporter); but as pointed out, most of them will require root. [Bug Report Reader](http://www.appbrain.com/app/bug-report-reader/uk.co.weavr.BugReportReader) however claims to *read system logs (logcat, dumpsys, dmesg, top and much more) on your device, without root*, so that might be worth trying.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, if USB debugging is turned on, you can use `adb logcat` to see the exception output. This usually includes a stack trace, but that's not often useful unless you have the app's source code. All the same, the developer of the app will probably be grateful if you include it in any bug report.

Comment: Thanks, I'd prefer a native solution directly on the device if possible. good point about the usefulness, doesn't the trace at least include sensibly named java exceptions? or does dalvik obfuscate them?

Comment: There are apps to read the log from the device (search Google Play for *logcat*), but in Jelly Bean and later, apps can't read each other's logs, so you might need to root your device to do this. The trace includes Java exception names, but `NullPointerException` doesn't really tell you a lot unless you're the app developer.

Comment: good point about that exception :/ since I rooted my device anyway, I was hoping for a more comfortable way than logcat, though that's better than nothing...

Answer (score 0):

Read the files under `/data/anr/` which stands for "apps not responding". I use `adb shell cat /data/anr/$FILE`

There will be one for every app which force closes, or is not responding for some reason.

Comment: When looking at /data/anr/ in a root file explorer, there's only a single traces.txt which was modified three days ago (even though an app crashed today), and it appears to contain only system crashes, not app crashes. Is there another way too see those app backtraces?